# What NoSQL database is good for developing a Wiki?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

What NoSQL database do you recommend for developing a Wiki-like application?

I need documents to have many sub-section texts, and each can be versioned controlled, and yet normalized.

Think of a Wikipedia page. It has many sections, and being a Wiki, it has version control for the document. However, I do not want a new document to be created (or the document being entirely duplicated) everytime a paragraph is changed. I only want that particular paragraph (or section) to have a new version, so it won't waste space on storage.

Any recommendation on the database or the design strategy?

Answer (score 4):

Currently no NoSQL database provides what you want here (as far as I know). The closest to what you want is the CouchDB which keeps document revision history on every update. The disk space is cheap so generally it's not a problem.

But if versioning is the key to your business and one of the business requirements you should choose a tool that is built specifically to solve this problem - Git. Git does exactly what you want and does a lot of heavy lifting for your wiki app (like version diffs, easy blame in other words who did what changes, has hooks etc.).

A great example is GitHub wiki pages. Their wiki engine built on git ([Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum)) is open-sourced.

To conclude, here are your options:

- use git
- CouchDB that does revision tracking for you, but as far as I
  know saves a copy of the document
- implement the revision logic in
  your app, any NoSQL db would fit nicely.

Comment: "You cannot rely on document revisions for any other purpose than concurrency control.

Due to compaction, revisions may disappear at any time. You cannot use them for a client revision system." - https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_revisions